# Debian apt-get install asks for the DVD Binary

Tags: debian, usb, synaptic

I have installed debian 8 jessie via usb stick on my thinkpad x250 (the laptop doesn't have any cd-dvd rom). Now when i want to use the synaptic or install some programms (especifically pure data) via: `sudo apt-get install puredata` i get this in terminal:

Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Debian GNU/Linux 8.4.0 *Jessie* - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20160402-13:26'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter

Why this happens and how am i supposed to insert a dvd when i haven't any dvd-rom? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installer considers that the USB stick you used for installation is a CD or DVD image; it left a reference to it in `/etc/apt/sources.list` as a source of packages for later.

If you only wish to install packages from the Internet, you can remove the line mentioning `cdrom:` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then update the package cache with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You could use the USB stick again but that would be somewhat more complicated.

Comment: The easier thing would be to just comment it out, in case you want to use it again later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and comment out the line beginning with `deb cdrom:`. Use the editor of your choice to add a `#` directly before `deb cdrom:` save the file and then run `sudo apt-get update`.